# How add objects to group on fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I want add rects to group dynamically. But when I add over top or left side, top left corner of group jump to top left corner of added rect. Help me resolve it, please.

How I add rects:

```
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('draw');
let group = new fabric.Group('', {
                     objectCaching: false,
                     hasControls: false,
                     hasBorders: false,
                     hasRotatingPoint: false,
                     subTargetCheck: true,
                });
group.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Rect({top:0,left:0,width:100,height:200}));
canvas.add(group);
canvas.renderAll();
group.on('moving', move);
function move(e) {
    let trCorner = e.target.calcCoords().tr;
    let viewPortTSide = e.target.canvas.calcViewportBoundaries().tl.y;
    if (viewPortTSide - trCorner.y < -10) {
        group.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Rect({top:-400,left:-200, height: 300, width: 200}))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are adding rect to group on move? If u keep on dragging, then it gonna add lot of object. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That just example, in real project i need dynamically load images. There are so much code, and i attach  example with rects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58572484/3551786

Comment: I don't want use several groups, it's will be difficult for positioning and adding new items to group. Can I just add new rect to group and then move it to some coords in group?

Comment: Do `group.add(rect);group.addWithUpdate()`

Comment: By the way. I tested you option. When i add one new item it's push on correct position and corner not jumping,  but it's not in group, i cant drag for it all group. And when i add one more item, both items jump to incorrect position.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle so that we can help you with this? What version of FabricJs are you using ?