# Confusion about group capabilities of fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have been experimenting with fabricjs lately. I am attempting to create a group structure (hierarchy) of layers similar to a raster editor like krita/gimp, conceptually. In other words, there may be groups inside of groups. From a few other questions it appears that this should be supported, but I am confused due to two seemingly inconsistent behaviors. I would appreciate it if someone could break down what assumptions I am making incorrectly.

-Positioning of items in groups. After creating a simple hierarchy the relative positions of my groups do not seem to make sense (positioning of parent group does not seem to apply)   https://jsfiddle.net/od259pct/3/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("t2", {
         // preserveObjectStacking : true
      });
      canvas.setHeight(130);
      canvas.setWidth(130);
      var layers = {};
      var layer_groups = {};

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
  'fill':'red'

})

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
  'fill':'yellow'

})

// contains groups 2 and 3
// modifying "top" and "left" seems to have no effect?
var group1 = new fabric.Group([],{
'top':50,
  'left':20,

})

//will contain rect1 (red)
var group2 = new fabric.Group([],{
'top':0,
  'left':0,

})

// will contain rect2 (yellow)
var group3 = new fabric.Group([],{
'top':0,
  'left':0,
  })


group1.addWithUpdate(group2)
group2.addWithUpdate(rect1)
canvas.add(group1)
group1.addWithUpdate(group3)
group3.addWithUpdate(rect2)
```

-Z-index of groups. I see multiple answers proposing either using .moveTo() or group.bringForward() However, neither of these seem to have any effect on groups inside groups. Secondly, it is never explained whether the index values that are used in these functions are absolute for the entire canvas or just within that group. https://jsfiddle.net/od259pct/4/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("t2", {
     // preserveObjectStacking : true
  });
  canvas.setHeight(130);
  canvas.setWidth(130);
  var layers = {};
  var layer_groups = {};

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
  'fill':'red'

})

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
  'fill':'yellow'

})

// contains groups 2 and 3
var group1 = new fabric.Group([],{
'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
})

//will contain rect1 (red)
var group2 = new fabric.Group([],{
'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
})

// will contain rect2 (yellow)
var group3 = new fabric.Group([],{
'top':0,
  'left':0,
  'width':30,
  'height':30,
})


group1.add(group2)
group2.add(rect1)
canvas.add(group1)
group1.add(group3)
group3.add(rect2)

// none of these seem to work (trying to move the yellow rect group under the red rect group)
group1.sendBackwards(group3)
canvas.sendBackwards(group3)

// nor these
group1.bringForwards(group2)
canvas.bringForwards(group2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[group#addWithUpdate](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#addWithUpdate) will update dimension and position. Just call add while adding to group, after adding the objects call `group.addWithUpdate()` to update the dimension.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("t2", {
  // preserveObjectStacking : true,
  width: 130,
  height:130
});

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
  'width': 30,
  'height': 30,
  'fill': 'red'
})

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
  'width': 30,
  'height': 30,
  'fill': 'yellow'
})

// contains groups 2 and 3
// modifying "top" and "left" seems to have no effect?
var group1 = new fabric.Group([], {
  'top': 50,
  'left': 20,
})

//will contain rect1 (red)
var group2 = new fabric.Group([], {
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
})

// will contain rect2 (yellow)
var group3 = new fabric.Group([], {
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
})
canvas.add(group1)

group1.add(group2)
group2.addWithUpdate(rect1)

group1.add(group3)
group3.addWithUpdate(rect2)
group1.addWithUpdate()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="t2-cont" >
  <canvas id="t2" style="border:black solid 2px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

And to change the positions of object call `moveTo` on grouped object.

***DEMO***

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("t2", {
  // preserveObjectStacking : true,
  width: 130,
  height:130
});

const rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
  'width': 30,
  'height': 30,
  'fill': 'red'
})

const rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
  'width': 30,
  'height': 30,
  'fill': 'yellow'
})

// contains groups 2 and 3
// modifying "top" and "left" seems to have no effect?
const group1 = new fabric.Group([], {
  'top': 50,
  'left': 20,
})

//will contain rect1 (red)
const group2 = new fabric.Group([], {
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
})

// will contain rect2 (yellow)
const group3 = new fabric.Group([], {
  'top': 0,
  'left': 0,
})
canvas.add(group1)

group1.add(group2)
group2.addWithUpdate(rect1)

group1.add(group3)
group3.addWithUpdate(rect2)
group1.addWithUpdate()

setTimeout(()=> {
  group2.moveTo(1);
  group1.addWithUpdate();
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="t2-cont" >
  <canvas id="t2" style="border:black solid 2px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for creating these, but some explanation is needed: why is "addWithUpdate" called without argument? Should it be called only for some groups or all of them, and how do you determine which groups (it seems to change the positioning if called for the other groups). Also, changing left and top of group2 and grouup3 seems to have no effect. For z-index, why do we call if for group1? Should this always be called for all groups with group children? Need some documented rules to use this in a consistent manner!

Comment: @Rboreal_Frippery, it is better to add objects, while creating a group. If you want to add it later, then call `addWithUpdate` which will update the dimension of group and if object is passed as parameter then position as well. If you use moveTo on grouped object it will change zindex in `group._objects` array. If you want to call group1 in your case parent group, it will change with respect to `canvas._objects`. If @Andrea see this post, he may answer this better.

Comment: This description of add vs addWithUpdate does not seem to make sense. It seems that the order of using .addWithUpdate() at the end makes a difference? How do you predict the correct order to call it in for a consistent result? Here https://jsfiddle.net/wfnb0o25/ I have tried to reproduce your suggestion: the purple and blue rects are correct, but the red one should be (30, 30) and not (60, 30) like it is. Every combination of add() and addWithUpdate() I have tried does not get it right. Do you know which @Andrea I should be reaching out to?

Comment: For your case, it works [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/tuhr7dp9/). Better ask a question on repo, [from here](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/new?template=help-with-my-own-project.md), and link this question there.